# Understanding observer in monix

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monix

I'm reading [***Monix documentation***](https://monix.io/docs/3x/reactive/observers.html#building-an-observer) about observers ad I faced with the following example:

> Or you can quickly build an Observer that only logs the events that it
> receives. We’ll use this in other samples:
>
> ```
> import monix.reactive.Observer
>
> val out = Observer.dump("O")
> // out: Observer.Sync[Any]
>
> out.onNext(1)
> //=> 0: O-->1
> // res0: Ack = Continue
>
> out.onNext(2)
> //=> 1: O-->2
> // res0: Ack = Continue
>
> out.onComplete()
> //=> 2: O completed
> ```

Yet the next ILLEGAL example:

> Feeding two elements, then stopping. This is NOT legal:
>
> ```
> // BAD SAMPLE
> observer.onNext(1)
> observer.onNext(2)
> observer.onComplete()
> ```

So we can see the same `onNext -> onNext -> onComplete` chain. Is it not legal? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation that you've linked, it's explained directly after the example

This is the legal way of doing it:

```
observer.onNext(1).map {
  case Continue =>
    // We have permission to continue
    observer.onNext(2)
    // No back-pressure required here
    observer.onComplete()
    Stop
  case Stop =>
    // Nothing else to do
    Stop
}
```

As you can see in the comments, the issue is *back-pressure*. So why is there an example, using `.dump` that seems to be illegal?

Note the comments in that example:

```
//=> 0: O-->1
// res0: Ack = Continue
```

These comments are showing what you would get if you ran this in the Scala REPL. When you enter an expression and hit return, the REPL prints something like `res0` and lets you know what the return value of the last command was.

So this example is demonstrating:

- Feeding an Observer from the REPL
- That each `.onNext` has completed with `Continue`

It wouldn't be correct to write a program that feeds an Observer in this way, but this is a *correct* transcription of a *legal* execution of feeding an observer.

You can see the rules relating to back-pressure under the [Contract section](https://monix.io/docs/3x/reactive/observers.html#contract):

> 2. Back-pressure: each onNext call MUST wait on a Continue result returned by the Future[Ack] of the previous onNext call.
> 3. Back-pressure for onComplete and onError is optional: when calling onComplete or onError you are not required to wait on the Future[Ack] of the previous onNext.

This is a good point to dwell on as elegant back-pressure management is one of the big promises of reactive streams.

Comment: If I understood correctly the problem with incorrect example is that we don't back-pressure after `onNext(1)`, but immediately call `onNext(2)` so any time we feed the observer we need to `map`. Seems like not stack-safe...

Comment: Whether or not it's stacksafe is down to Monix's `.map` implementation. A number of similar libraries use some kind of Trampoline or lazy implementation to prevent stack issues. Either way I'm sure Monix is stacksafe.

Comment: But yes, your description is how I understand it as well